# Can I specify the sync frequency on Google Drive on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, sync, google-drive

I want my Google Drive sync my local files with the server files every 10 minutes. I mean, I don't want it trying to sync constantly. Where can I specify that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not seem possible. The approved answer on [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/VMIjqrWsvCw/ikDSwpwGLUsJ) on the Google product forums specifically states "Drive syncs automatically when you add/delete files from the Drive folder on your computer."

There is a program called [@MAX SyncUp](https://www.maxsyncup.com/how_to/setup_google_drive.html) that states it can "copy data on schedule or only when files are changed". It is free for personal non-commercial use, but the free version has the restriction that you can only set up one synchronization or backup profile.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the option to include this executable on Windows Startup and then use the Windows Task Scheduler to open the exe at whatever interval you choose (30 mins, 24 hours...literally any interval).

I'm not positive exactly *how* (but positive *that*) you can wait until it is "done" [sync-ing] to close it back out (since I presume your choice here is to eliminate it's impact on other things in your Windows environment (network throughput, CPU, whatever).

Comment: Never came across Task Scheduler before.
Fantastic resource! Thank you.